# Calling a Activity method from BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, static-methods

Here I am creating an online application that depends only on Internet.

So whenever there is a network error it must notify user. For that, I have created a BroadcastReciver that receives call when network connection gets lost(Internet).

All this works perfectly. Now what I need is that I have to call a method of Activity from this Broadcast Receiver, where I have created an Alert Dialogue.

I have read many answers on stack-overflow.com that I can declare that method static and call by using only Activity name,

e.g `MyActivityName.myMethod()`

But I can't declare my method static, because I am using Alert Dialogue there and it shows me error on line,

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

that **Cannot use this in a static context**.

So, how can I call a method of Activity(must not static and without starting that activity) from a Broadcast Receiver ?

And can I get Activity(or fragment) name from Broadcast Receiver which is currently running?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try this code :

your broadcastreceiver class for internet lost class :

```
public class InternetLostReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("INTERNET_LOST"));
}
}
```

in your activity add this for calling broadcast:

```
public class TestActivity  extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("INTERNET_LOST"));
}

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // internet lost alert dialog method call from here...
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code jay,it works perfectly.
I have put a code for creating Alert Dialogue in onReceive().
Only one bug is there.
Whenever internet gets disconnects , four Alert Dialogues created instantly instead of one.

Comment: please put if condition for opening AlertDialog if opened than don't open another. Please, if its work than accept my answer.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialog.setMessage("Network not found.");
  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Check Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
   {
   }
  });
   
  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
   {
       
   }
  }); 
  alertDialog.show();

Comment: A side note: the internal `BroadcastReceiver` must not have the same intent filter as the external `BroadcastReceiver`. If they do, you'll get an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks you saved my time :)

Comment: It works perfectly, but can you please explain to me the logic behind this, i am not getting it

Answer (score 10):

## INTERFACE: Keep BroadCastReceiver and Activity code separate!

You can make a CallBackListener interface. The interface will work as a bridge between `BroadcastReceiver` and `Activity`.

**1) Create a CallbackListener**

```
interface ConnectionLostCallback{

      public void connectionLost();

}
```

**2) Provide `ConnectionLostCallback` in your BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

     private ConnectionLostCallback listener;

     public MyBroadcastReceiver(ConnectionLostCallback listener ){

           this.listener = listener     //<-- Initialze it

     }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           listener.connectionLost();

     }
}
```

**3) Implement the `ConnectionLostCallback` in your Activity and override the method**

```
YourActvity extends AppcompatActivity implements ConnectionLostCallback{

    // Your Activity related code //
      //    new MyBroadcastReceiver(this);  <-- create instance

    private void showAlertMessage(){
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    } 


    @Override 
    public void connectionLost(){

         showAlertMessage();          //<--- Call the method to shoe alert dialog

    }


}
```

## Relevant link:

> If you want to know how to make a BroadcastReceiver independent of any
>   activity ie How can you reuse the same BroadCastReceiver with
>   different Activities?       Then [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver/54364171#54364171)

Comment: what about if you cannot call the constructor? For example, when using AlarmManager, the broadcastreceiver is called from the alarmmanager methods

Comment: Same situation if you wnt to track wifi state changes - thats at the manifest level and you catch system level broadcasts.  In that case, set up a listener

Comment: am also using alarmmanger, to fix this issue am using localbroadcastmanager instead of interface as callback @mantc_sdr

Comment: here is my code in broadcast receiver:Intent refreshIntent = new Intent("CALLBACK");
       refreshIntent.putExtra("STATUS", byReminderType);
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(refreshIntent)

Answer (score 4):

Add a boolean variable in you activity from where you are open alertdialog

```
boolean isDialogOpened = false;

// in broadcast recever check 
if(isDialogOpened) {
    alertDialog();
}
```

And replace your code for alertdialog with this one

```
public void alertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setMessage("Network not found.");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Check Setting",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            isDialogOpened = false;
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            isDialogOpened = false;
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: sorry but your code not working,
Telling me "NoSuchMethodException" on alertDialog.setonDismissListenet

Answer (score 1):

**Pass your Activity's context to BroadcastReceiver's contructor.**

```
public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    MainActivity ma; //a reference to activity's context

    public ResponseReceiver(MainActivity maContext){
        ma=maContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ma.brCallback("your string"); //calling activity method
    }

}
```

and in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    public void onStart(){
        ...        
    ResponseReceiver responseReceiver = new ResponseReceiver(this); //passing context
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(responseReceiver,null);
        ...
    }

    public void brCallback(String param){
        Log.d("BroadcastReceiver",param);
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't think that works, because `brCallback` is not a valid message for `AppCompatActivity`. And sure, you could cast your activity down, but then you end up coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Use *lambdas*. A `Consumer` would do.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    receiver = new LocationBroadcastReceiver((whatever) -> doSomething(whatever));
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("YOUR_MESSAGE"));
}
```

Where `doSomething` will be a method in your **Activity**.

...

```
class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Consumer<Whatever> callback;

    public LocationBroadcastReceiver(Consumer<Whatever> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            
        this.callback.accept(new Whatever());
    }
}
```

Is the alternative to all the other:

> declare that method static and call by using only Activity name.

Apart from what you explained, that's a way of coupling.

> pass your Activity's context to BroadcastReceiver's contructor.

That wouldn't work because you want to call a method that's not part of `AppCompatActivity`. And yeah, you could downcast, but then you end up coupled to your activity.

> using another Broadcast or a Local Broadcasts instead

Well, you can only pass a bunch of primitives that way. What if you want to pass an object? Also, declaring a new BroadcastReceiver get quite verbose and maybe hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Vijju' s answer but using Local Broadcasts instead

```
public class SampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentToBroadcast =  new Intent("YOUR_ACTION_HERE");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToBroadcast);
    }
}
```

In your activity add this

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mSampleReceiver, new IntentFilter(YOUR_ACTION_HERE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mSampleReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private SampleReceiver mSampleReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // your code here
        }
    };
}
```

**Note** Move the register/unregister calls to onCreate/onDestroy is you want to be notified even when your activity is in the background.

Comment: When I want to declare a variable like you did: "private SampleReceiver mSampleReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()", give me error that Require type: SampleReceiver but provided is BroadcastReceiver

Comment: try replacing new BroadcastReceiver() with new SampleReceiver()