# notifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

My adapter list is refreshing on broadcast receiver .

> Everything is working fine if adapter list size is greater than 1 ,
>   means if my recyclerview has already one row shwoing then list refreshing just fine .
>   But if list size goes from 0 to 1 then my adapter notify dataset
>   Changed stop working . No data shows on recyclerview. I don't know why it is not working .

**Recyclerview Class:**

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_recyclerview, container, false);
getActivity());
        initialise(v);
        init();
        showNoTaskMessage();
        new loadListTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Here you can refresh your listview or other UI


                SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(0).setText("New (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getNewjob() + ")");
                SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(1).setText("In Progress (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getInprogressjob() + ")");;
                SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(2).setText("Completed (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getCompletedjob() + ")");

            }

        };

        try {

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("newJob");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver,
                    filter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

**Adapter class :**

```
 public JobAdapter(ArrayList<Info> myDataset, Context context) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
        this.mAct = context;
    }

    public void addApplications(ArrayList<Info> candidates) {
        if (this.filterList == null) {
            filterList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.mDataset.clear();
        this.mDataset.addAll(candidates);
        this.filterList.addAll(mDataset);
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size() - 1);

    }

    public void clearApplications() {
        int size = this.mDataset.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                mDataset.remove(0);
                filterList.remove(0);
            }

            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return VIEW_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_job_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder fh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return fh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//        holder.jobPhone.setText(mDataset.get(position).mobileNo);
        holder.jobNumber.setText(mDataset.get(position).jobNumber);
        holder.jobTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).time);
        holder.jobAddress.setText(mDataset.get(position).address);
//        holder.jobInstructionText.setText(mDataset.get(position).spclInstruction);

        if (mDataset.get(position).jobStatus != null && mDataset.get(position).jobStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")) {
            holder.endsat.setText("Submitted at");
            holder.jobTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).completedOnString);
            holder.jobTimeLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.timerImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            if (mDataset.get(position).status.equalsIgnoreCase("Active")) {
                holder.jobTimeLeft.setText(mDataset.get(position).appointmentTime);
            } else {
                holder.jobTimeLeft.setText("-" + mDataset.get(position).appointmentTime);
            }
        }

        holder.jobLayout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SingleTon.getInstance().setWorkDescHolder(mDataset.get(position).descHolder);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) mAct).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) mAct).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_in, R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_out);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame1, new DetailsFragment(), "persondetails");
                ft.addToBackStack("persondetails");

                // Start the animated transition.
                ft.commit();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView jobNumber, jobTimeLeft, jobStatus, jobAddress, jobEmail, jobPhone, timeTimer, jobInstructionText, jobTime, endsat;
        private ImageView timerImage;
        private FrameLayout frameLayout;
        private CardView cardView;
        private LayoutRipple jobLayout1;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.jobNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.job_number);
            this.jobTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.job_time);
            this.jobTimeLeft = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.job_timertext);
            this.timerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.timerimage);
            this.cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
//            this.jobStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.job_status);
            this.jobAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.job_addresstext);
//            this.jobInstructionText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.instruction_text);
//            this.jobLayout = (LayoutRipple)v.findViewById(R.id.job_cardLayout);
            this.jobLayout1 = (LayoutRipple) v.findViewById(R.id.cardLayout1);
            this.endsat = (AppCompatTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.endsat);
            this.jobNumber.setTypeface(Utils.RegularTypeface(mAct));
            this.jobAddress.setTypeface(Utils.RegularTypeface(mAct));
            this.jobTimeLeft.setTypeface(Utils.RegularTypeface(mAct));
            this.jobTime.setTypeface(Utils.RegularTypeface(mAct));
        }
    }
}
```

**Please help me finding the bug or some other approach . Thanks**

Comment: See if this line is problematic `this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size() - 1);`

Comment: @random what should i change it to?

Comment: second arg in the method is item count but if your candidates size is one subtracting one means 0 item count. try changing second arg to just candidates.size()

Comment: @random no still not working

Comment: if this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size()) doesn't work then try changing it to notifyDataSetChanged and check if it works. If it does then there might be a problem with parameters passed in notifyItemRangeInserted.

Comment: try to log `mDataset.size()` inside `getItemCount()` and see if it really updates every time you expect to refresh your recyclerview

Comment: @random i have changed  this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size()) to this.notifydatasetchnaged . but still not working though mdatasize showing correct count .

Comment: try to update `reyclerview` in a UI thread from broadcast receiver as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869928/android-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-update-textview-in-mainactivity

Comment: @random    but i am receiving my broadcast in recyclerview class only then getting instance of it  and all i think might be not a right way.

Comment: @Gautam   i have changed this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size()) to this.notifydatasetchnaged

Comment: Its not about where your broadcast receiver is. Once you receive your data in receiver, UI should be updated on UI thread else changes wont reflect. Give it a chance and let us know if it helps.

Comment: @random ohkay i will try . So,where should i put the updateMethod in adapter?

Comment: @random still not working .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120500/discussion-between-random-and-young-08).

Comment: In your broadcastreceiver, the only real difference between if/else is how you add the list to addApplications, why don't you first try to just directly insert `SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList()` just like your if-part, comment out that addAll part for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the data loading task inside the `onReceive()` of `BroadcastReceiver`

```
    mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Here you can refresh your listview or other UI
           new loadListTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(0).setText("New (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getNewjob() + ")");
            SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(1).setText("In Progress (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getInprogressjob() + ")");;
            SlidingTab.slidingTab.getTabAt(2).setText("Completed (" + SingleTon.getInstance().getCompletedjob() + ")");

        }

    };
```

And also do following changes in your **Adapter** class.

```
   public void addApplications(ArrayList<Info> candidates) {
        if (this.filterList == null) {
            filterList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.mDataset.clear();
        this.mDataset.addAll(candidates);
        this.filterList.addAll(mDataset);
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size());

    }

    public void clearApplications() {
        int size = this.mDataset.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                mDataset.remove(i);
                filterList.remove(i);
            }

            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

**Change this:**

```
mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        // Here you can refresh your listview or other UI
                        recycleAdapter.addItems(SingleTon.getInstance()
                                         .getInfoArrayList());

                        // I'm assuming your "SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList()" is the received data.
                    }
```

On your **Adapter**

```
public void addItems(List<Info> itemsList) {
    // This check could be avoided if you declared your mDataset final
    if(mDataset == null) {
        mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    int prevSize = mDataset.size();
    mDataset.addAll(itemsList);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(prevSize, itemsList.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call notifyDataSetChanged() after `this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size() - 1);` try something like this:

put this method to your adapter class

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Info> infos) {
   this.mDataset = infos;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
ArrayList<Info> list = SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList().isEmpty();
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
    recycleAdapter.setData(list);
}
```

correct this method in your adapter

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset != null && !mDataset.isEmpty() ? mDataset.size() : 0;
}
```

Comment: done all the changes according to suggestion but still not working

Comment: You can update your question. Put your new code below **UPDATE:** header.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, we need a variable list to store your info data.

```
//Declare the info list
private ArrayList<Info> mInfos = new ArrayList<Info>()
```

In your `onCreateView()`, set `mInfos` to your `recycleAdapter`

```
recycleAdapter =  new JobAdapter(mInfos, getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
```

So, every time you want to set new info list. Just assign it to `mInfos`
and make sure, you clear your previous list data to avoid duplicate data.

```
mInfos.clear()
mInfos.addAll(SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList());
//refresh data
recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are using clearApplications() in JobAdapter.class.
But, it seems to be wrong. In the for-loop, you are trying to remove the value at index 0 every time rather than index 'i'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

when you are using custom adapter then notifyDatasetChange() not called from outside that adapter so make addItem function in adapter and add new List in Adapter list and call notifyDataSetChanged

```
public void addItem(List<Model> list) {
    if (lit != null) {
        clear();
        adapterList.addAll(list);

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: if you look at my adapter code which i pasted , you will find i exactly did this .

Answer (score -1):

Do Change In your recyclerview class.

```
//Change condition ">1" to "!=null"

if (SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList().size() != null) {
recycleAdapter.addApplications(SingleTon.getInstance().getInfoArrayList());
recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and then do change in your adapter.

```
public void addApplications(ArrayList<Info> candidates) {
    if (this.filterList == null) {
        filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.mDataset.clear();
    this.mDataset.addAll(candidates);
    this.filterList.addAll(mDataset);
    this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mDataset.size()); //notify to mDataset
}
```

hope this will work!