# issue with listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); into onReceive()

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

i need to get object `list view` in `broadcast receiver` class...
but if i write `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);` i get error.

Any ideas?

THANKS in advance everybody!

I hope that you can help me!

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private Intent intent;
    String value1 = null;
    String value2 = null;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> al;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ArrayList<Sms> dataSms;
    public static CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;

 /*   @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      //  TextView textView = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
}
```

Comment: post your code and error log

Comment: "Error:(39, 31) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)"

Comment: Please post the code which causes the problem. Be sure to include the class and method declarations as well as all relevant variable declarations.

Comment: Don't update listView data in broadcast receiver class. Create one public static  method in MainActivity class and call that method in broadcast receiver class. In that method, execute your code on UI thread. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869928/android-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-update-textview-in-mainactivity

Comment: It depends on BroadcastReceiver ... you need to make inner non static class of Activity/Fragment itself and don't forget to unregiser it in right lifecycle event

Comment: so i must use broadcast receiver as inner class of my main activity?

Comment: So you show some code ... now it's clear that's FUBAR .... you should not have any UI elements inside BroadcastReceiver  ... also if you register BroadcastReceiver inside manifes it lives only for the time of onReceive so having fields inside doesn't make sens at all

Comment: *so i must use broadcast receiver as inner class of my main activity?* if you wana change UI from it yes ... but if you need it to be registered in manifest (like on boot/alarm) then you need 2 BroadcastReceivers ... the one pointed in manifest(which would work as proxy) and second one inside the Activity ... the second one may be called view localbroadcastmanager ... you may also use some other subscriber observer pattern/event bus

Comment: @mdg5435 now list view delete first item but not send sms....

Comment: Delete/Update listView after smsManager.sendTextMessage(name, null, sms, null, null); code.

Answer (score 0):

make a class variable and initialize it in the onCreate method of your activity. once initialized it can be used from anywhere inside the class...

so:

```
private ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       ...
}
```

Hope that helps...

Cheers

Comment: i have problem to instance a list view into onReceive() in broadcast receiver class...not in activity

Comment: you don't instance a listView in onReceive().
initialize the listview as above and then use it in the onReceive()

onReceive(..){ lv.xxxxx;}

Comment: your code misses the following anyway: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activityName);`  right after onCreate and before anything else

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LayoutInflater mInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = mInf.inflate(R.layout.activity_favorite_list, null);
ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```