# Change item in ViewPager on alarm

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an app that resets every midnight to a default view.

So, I set up an alarm in my MainActivity, and an AlarmReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver

This is the AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Will be executed when Alarm is fired
        Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity

```
// VerticalViewPager & adapter
VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.verticalViewPager);
adapterViewPager = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
verticalViewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

In this example, the alarm fires off everyday at midnight, and write the toast message. What I want instead is that the alarm changes the current item displayed in ViewPager:

```
// Will set the view I want
verticalViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
```

But of course, I can't write this under the `onReceive` method because it doesn't know what `verticalViewPager` is. I'm new to OOP as well.

Comment: Check this: [Update in BroadcastReceiver.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870274/7831581)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to link AlarmReceiver with those components which are actually able to fully control verticalViewPager. 
E.g **EventBus**(little bit old), **RXjava**(Publish subject) , etc.

And if app does not always run in foreground at midnight, it's more like you need to deep link to the target page(MainActivity?), and then get the Viewpager updated.

Comment: If the app doesn't run at midnight it doesn't matter, I just do a Calendar comparaison, and set the pager to 3 onCreate if it's a different day than yesterday.