# Update UI into BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver

i'm new in android development(sorry for my english i'm french).
I want to create a chat app. Now I have a listview based on local database.

Also I have a broadcast receiver which check if the connection changed.
When the connection changed and is ok it update the local Database.
But i want that if the app is running that the list of message refresh.

How can I do that?
My list is linked with my local DB with a custom cursor adapter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use another intent and a broadcast receiver to notify every component of your app that the database has been updated. Instead of the Android components (intent + broadcast receiver) you can also use some event bus library like Otto to make the things easier.

Your activity subscribes to some business class in the `onCreate` method and unsubscribes from it in the `onDestroy`, so it always get notified from the changes when it is running.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this