# How to get access to the MainActivity findViewById from inside a Broadcast Receiver onReceive method?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

When I use this code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    seconds += 0.1;

    if (seconds > 59.9) {
        seconds=0;
        minutes++;
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView)((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.txtChron);
    tv.setText (String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
}
```

I get an error when trying to cast the context to `MainActivity`.

Here is the error / stack trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu, PID: 22693
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu.MY_TIME_TICK
>   flg=0x10 } in
>   com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu.ChronometerReceiver@d9365fe
>   at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1132)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be
>   cast to com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu.MainActivity at
>   com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu.ChronometerReceiver.onReceive(ChronometerReceiver.java:41)
>   at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1122)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

So I have a `MainActivity`, which starts a service.  The service creates a new thread, and this thread constantly created implicit intents which are handled by a `BroadcastReceiver`.  This broadcast receiver will update a clock, and update a `TextView` in the layout with the updated time. But when I try to get access to the `findViewByID` via the context parameter, I get the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `TextView` inside the `onCreate` function of your `Activity`.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtChron);
```

Then in your `onReceive` function

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    seconds += 0.1;
    if (seconds > 59.9) {
        seconds=0;
        minutes++;
    }

    tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.jordanbleu.lab8chronservjordanbleu.MainActivity

This means "Context context" is Application, not the MainActivity.

My suggestion is, inflate your TextView in OnCreate.

```
TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtChron); // This!
...
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    seconds += 0.1;

    if (seconds > 59.9) {
        seconds=0;
        minutes++;
    }

    tv.setText (String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use an interface. This way you will not have to access The UI element in the BroadcastReceiver.

**1) Create an interface:**

```
interface ReceiverListener {
    public void doSomething(String arg1, String arg2);
}
```

**2) Instantiate the Listener in your BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class YourBroadCastReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver{

    private ReceiverListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        listener = (ReceiverListener)context;  // Initialize listener 

        // Your logic 
        String minutes = //get it
        String seconds = // get it

       listener.doSomething(minutes,seconds); 

    }

}
```

**3) Implement the interface in Your Activity and override the method**

```
public YourActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements ReceiverListener{

     // Activity related code
    TextView tv;

    public void updateUI(String minutes,String seconds){
        tv.setText (minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }


    @Override 
    public void doSomething(String arg1, String arg2){
        updateUI(arg1,arg2);
    }

}
```

## Relevant Link:

If you want to see the advantage of using an interface in this case, [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver/54364171#54364171)