# broadcast Intent / receiver

Tags: java, android

In my Application I have a Broadcast receiver (registered in manifest) class from which I want to send an Intent to MainActivity. Therefore I have another broadcast receiver (dynamically registered) in MainActivity and an Intent Filter. But I don't receive the Intent in Main Activity.
This is the code:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    public SmsReceiver(){

    }
        String TAG = SmsReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] sms = (Object[]) bundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                String str = "";

                for (int i=0; i < sms.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                    String smsbody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += smsbody;
                }
                Intent bcIntent = new Intent();
                bcIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                bcIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                bcIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
                bcIntent.putExtra("message", str);
                context.sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
public boolean receivedSMS;
public String displaySMS;

  private BroadcastReceiver iReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String qqq = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    info2(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
    evalMsg(qqq);
  }
};

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    graphInit();
    timerInit();
    smnInit();

  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume(){

  super.onResume();
  IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
    iFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

    registerReceiver(iReceiver, iFilter);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(iReceiver);
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Does anyone know why the broadcast receiver in the main activity doesnt receive the intent? There should be a text displayed in the TextView but it is never shown. thanks for any idea

Comment: Can you please show your Manifest file.

Comment: Maybe some permission problem (After Android Marshmallow). Refer https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 0):

When receiving the intent via `SmsReceiver` you can't know if the Activity is up and in what state. 
What you should consider is using [`startActivity(android.content.Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) from within your `SmsReceiver.onReceive()`. This way you'll have the same intent object available within `Activity.onCreate` (just call the `getIntent()` method)

But if you want to stick to your original design of double broadcasts, then [here is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648933/5931191).